# Why is the Add button disabled in Azure Email Communication Services MailFrom address?

Tags: azure, email

I am using Azure Email Communication Service. I have setup a custom domain, and it is fully verified (SPF, DKIK, etc.). Sending email works. However, by default it has the MailFrom set to DoNotReply@mydomain.com.

I want to add my own MailFrom, e.g., support@mydomain.com. However, the 'Add' button disabled. How do I make it enabled?

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you!

(I made sure the domain verification is showing all green)

Comment: Same issue here. Created support request and waiting for response.

Comment: az cli operation will also fail with forbidden error.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your support. 
I later contacted MS Support. The answer from Lukas Nespor matches their response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR:

You need to send unspecified number of emails from DoNotReply@yourdomain.com and then request increase quota using support request.

### Response from Microsoft support:

ACS & ECS is currently undergoing very recent changes and the documentation is being updated.

Your ECS resource is on "Mercury" Throttling Tier/Default Tier, in said tier, now you won't be able to do the following:

1. Enable engagement tracking: How to configure user engagement tracking to an email domain with Azure Communication Service resource. - [An Azure Communication Services quick start guide | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/enable-user-engagement-tracking)
2. Add new MailFrom (sender usernames) to any domain (managed or custom), this includes Azure portal, API, CLI.
   If the ACS/ECS resource on the default sending limits, you can’t create new SenderUsername/MailFrom and the default sender email will be (DoNotReply@{your domain}) until the ACS/ECS on higher limit: How to add custom verified domains to Email Communication Service - [An Azure Communication Services quick start guide | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/add-custom-verified-domains#azure-managed-domains-vs-custom-domains)

The custom domain documentation is still in development, and will soon be updated.

If you'd like to add mailfrom addresses/sender usernames, you now need to upgrade your sending limits/tier. This process does not hold any costs.
To increase your limits, you should **start using your domain and generate some email traffic** from said domain/resource, then update us by opening a support ticket with the following route "Azure/Communication Services/Assistance with Email Services/Quota Increase".

[Service limits for Azure Communication Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/service-limits#action-to-take-3)

Comment: That support path requires having a paid support subscription. ACS/ECS isn't an option if I just go the subscription management ticket route. ‍♂️

Comment: Thanks very much Lukas for this explanation. 
Microsoft support team got back to me this morning, and pretty much said what you mentioned here.
It's apparently a new requirement!